# How many kg fresh figs is required to get 12 kg dried figs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, percentages, inverse-problems

> The price of fresh figs is Rs. 96 per kg. When it is dried the price
>   becomes Rs. 160 per kg. How many kg fresh figs is required to get 12
>   kg dried figs?

Options:

A) 12

B) 15

C) 18

D) 20

Comment: Hi guys, as I am new to this platform which is to help each other but not to deny, close or put-on-hold the questions asked by needy members obviously like me. You may please guide in this regards what to improve instead of cutting off the link with community. :( I am disappointed from the senior members here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that there are $160$ dried figs in a kg.  Adding water to them makes them heavier: $96/$kg.

$12$ kg of dried figs by this measure would be $12\cdot160 = 1920$ figs.  This corresponds to $1920/96 = 20$ kg of fresh figs.

Comment: Hi @John, please help me in following; The number of boys in a class is 10 less than twice the number of girls. Find the total number of students in the class, if the number of boys is 5 more than the number of girls.

Comment: You're welcome. Please ask this as a new question rather than in a comment.  Also, you'll generally get a better response from the community here if you show what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck, instead of just posting the question without any of these other things.  (In other words, a bit more effort into your questions will go a long way!)